# How to using ViewBag for Html.TextAreaFor()

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

HomeController

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.LongText = Feedback.GetComment(Id); //calling a function from another class file
            return View(); 
        }
```

This is the code I use for the **Html.TextArea** which is only been able to display the ViewBag data and can't POST the data

```
@Html.TextArea("txtComment", (string)(ViewBag.LongText), new { @class = "form-control"})
```

This is the **Html.TextAreaFor** which can POST data can can't display the ViewBag Data

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.txtComment, new { @class = "form-control"})
```

I tried to add **@value="@ViewBag.txtContent" but it won't works.

Comment: while using TextAreaFor try adding `txtComment = Feedback.GetComment(Id);` in controlller, then no need for viewbag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most important attribute for an element to have when it comes to actually performing a POST is the name attribute. The name attribute is what MVC uses to build your dictionary of keys and values that will be sent up to your form.

Try adding a name attribute to your TextArea.

```
@Html.TextArea("txtComment", (string)(ViewBag.LongText), new { @class = "form-control", name = "txtComment"})
```

Comment: Thanks For the help, I just realize theirs a Typo in my textArea no wonder it cant works